# InApp-Purchases in iOS didFailWithError:

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Using [Ray's good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) ...

Why I can not load the list of InApp-Purchases (**didFailWithError:** calls) from device but in simulator I can?

**EDITED**

If I run app on device `didFailWithError:` method calls:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Cannot load the list of products...");
NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.description);
_productsRequest = nil;

_completionHandler(NO, nil);
_completionHandler = nil;

}
```

This is the error description:

```
Error - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x1cdb19c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

**SOLVED**

I'm sorry guys but problem was in Proxy. Several sites (include Apple's sites) were closed.

Now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Check with which apple account you are accessing in the device. It should be a test account.

Comment: @coder284: if I try to login with test account there is server reply "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Comment: Did you check the points mentioned over there..

Go to Settings\iTunes & App Stores, log out of any account, and try again so you’re sure you’re using a Sandbox account.
Check this link – if it doesn’t respond, the iTunes sandbox may be down.
Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
Are you using the full product ID when making an SKProductRequest?
Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling?

Comment: @coder284: everything works on simulator and I have already bought my app ))) but on device I cannot get the list of products...
I have tried all your advices, but nothing (

Comment: @Romowski: Hi, what you mean by "the problem in proxy", can you explain how did you fix that? I am experiencing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @Malloc: hi! Simply several sites (including Apple's) were blocked by the proxy settings. Our system administrator unblocked it and it's fixed my problem. If your local network use proxy, you should enter proxy parameters to wi-fi settings of your device. Keep coding ))

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Resolved my problem (Y)

Answer (score 6):

The simulator doesn't facilitate in-app purchases, you have to test this on device. Check that each device is currently using a test account *and* that these test accounts are registered on iTunes Connect. See Test User section therein. When an invitation goes out, be sure to click the link in the received email to confirm. Failing this, check that the test users are registered to the appropriate store.

For what it's worth, in case it helps at all I'll add that I've seen test users confuse Game Center and App Store sign in for IAP.

Comment: doh! but happy for you. I'll keep this in mind for when it happens to me.